# Branch Coverage Issue

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm rather stuck on why I'm not getting 100% test branch coverage in my tests for this piece of code:

```
    public List<ReturnItem> FilterItems(List<Items> items)
    {
        if (items== null || !items.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No items to filter");
        }

        var newItems = new List<NewItem>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Tracking.MidStateDate != null)
            {
                if (orderLine.Tracking.EndStateDate.GetValueOrDefault() < orderLine.Tracking.MidStateDate)
                {
                    var newItem = new NewItem(item);
                    newItem.MidStateDate = item.Tracking.MidStateDate.Value;
                    newItems.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
        }

        return newItems;
    }
```

I've got the following tests:

- NoItems();
- HasItems_NullTracking();
- HasItems_NoTracking();
- HasItems_HasTracking_NoMidStateDate();
- HasItems_HasTracking_HasMidStateDate_NullEndStateDate();
- HasItems_HasTracking_HasMidStateDate_SmallerEndStateDate();
- HasItems_HasTracking_HasMidStateDate_EndStateDateIsEqual();
- HasItems_HasTracking_HasMidStateDate_LargerEndStateDate();
- HasItems_HasTracking_HasMidStateDate_MixedState();

I cannot get the branch coverage tests to 100%.  Which makes me think I'm missing something.  I've removed most of the code, and found that the issue is to do with this conditional `if (orderLine.Tracking.EndStateDate.GetValueOrDefault() < orderLine.Tracking.MidStateDate)`.

Can anyone suggest any other unit tests that I can add to handle the branch coverage issue?

Comment: It's more likely that the tool that's calculating the coverage is wrong.  In general trying to get 100% coverage should not be your goal, something around 90% is more reasonable (or less based on the code base size).

Comment: It looks like you don't have a test for the very first path, where `items` is `null` (which should throw `ArgumentNullException`, not the base `ArgumentException`, incidentally). This is not the same as having "no items".

Comment: @madreflection Unfortunately, it's not that

Comment: @juharr While I agree it's a bit OTT, it's a requirement for codebase I'm working on.  I would be quite annoyed if I've lost a day to a dotnet core SDK bug, not that it hasn't happened before.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, guys.

Comment: Maybe try `if (orderLine.Tracking.EndStateDate == null || orderLine.Traking.EndStateDate.Value < orderLine.Tracking.MidStateDate)`  That should be the same logic (assuming that `MidStateDate` is never `DateTime.MinValue`) but maybe the code determining the coverage will handle it better.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for that suggestion.  I've tried and it still hasn't worked.  It seems test coverage in dotnet has an issue with nullable dates.

Comment: It should be impossible to get 100% code coverage. You just end up adding pointless, useless tests that make your code base harder to maintain, not easier.

Comment: [I would expect a coverage percentage in the upper 80s or 90s. I would be suspicious of anything like 100% - it would smell of someone writing tests to make the coverage numbers happy, but not thinking about what they are doing.](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html)

Comment: @Liam That is not a view that I disagree with.  It's a system requirement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brainwave just as I replied to @juharr.

The issue was with the code not being explicit with the nullable datetime in the problematic conditional.

```
if (orderLine.Tracking.EndStateDate.GetValueOrDefault() < orderLine.Tracking.MidStateDate)
```

^ Causes an issue

```
if (orderLine.Tracking.EndStateDate.GetValueOrDefault() < orderLine.Tracking.MidStateDate.Value)
```

^ Works!